# Can you provide a module by another name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In our application we use our own logging framework. Some of the external modules we use uses the [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) module, which logs directly to the console.

I would like to wrap these logging calls, so that they are piped through our own framework.

I didn't want to override/hook `console.log`, because that's what our logging framework uses internally (and it feels dirty). So my next idea was to somehow instruct Node to load my own code when another module uses `require('debug')`. Is that possible? And, if so, how? Or is there maybe a better solution altogether?

Comment: Load your code in debug?

Comment: @DrakaSAN What do you mean?

Comment: Well, either add your framework to debug (but I doubt it would be easy) or wrap debug in your framework?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, we just [forked debug](https://github.com/hartwig-at/debug) and we're now simply using our fork in our project.

We adjusted the fork to make use of our own logging solution. Integrating it was pretty easy, due to the support of [GitHub URLs in package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#GitHub-URLs).